# detect if ajax call succeeded or not

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, razor

Here is my ajax call

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "MyMethod",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify({  Param1: 'value1', Param2: 'value2'}),
            success: function (msg) { location.href = '@Url.Action("MyActionMethod", "MyController")'; },
            error: function (msg) { alert(msg); }
        });
```

This is my model

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Param1 { get; set; }
    public string Param2 { get; set; }
}
```

MyMethod implementation is as follows

```
public bool MyMethod(MyModel model)
{

    if (!ValidateModel(model) )
    {
        // I want to error a descriptive error  
        return false;
    }

    // Some other processing
    return true;
}
```

Problem is that I don't know how does it determine if call is a success or failure. Returning ture/false does not seem to help as code always go in the success code path (that is it redirects to MyController.MyActionMethod). Any ideas what i am doing wrong

Comment: Actions should return `ActionResult`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is usually what I do:

```
public JsonResult MyMethod(MyModel model)
{
    var success = true;
    var result = string.Empty;

    if (!ValidateModel(model) )
    {
        // I want to error a descriptive error  
        success = false;
        result = "Invalid model";
    }

    // Some other processing
    return Json(new { success = success, error = result }, 
        JsonRequestBehavior.Allow);
}
```

Note the change in the return method from `bool` to `JsonResult`. And then in your JavaScript you could test the properties coming through on the JSON object:

```
...
success: function (msg) { 
   if (msg.success) {
       location.href = '@Url.Action("MyActionMethod", "MyController")'; 
   } else {
       alert(msg.error);
   }
},
...
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to trigger jQuery's `error` handler, you need to return an HTTP error.
To do that, set `Response.StatusCode` to `400` (Bad Request).

Alternatively, you can return JSON from the action and read properties object in the `success` handler to get an error message or a URL.

Comment: Yes; you can return `Json(...)` or `Content(...)`

Comment: +1: I agree with SLaks and don't recommend you to use successful HTTP status codes in the failed response. @imak: I would recommend you to use the way like described [here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=496) to return JSON formatted response in case of any exception in the server code. So you can use `success` handler of `jQuery.ajax` to decode successful responses and decode *another* fornatted error JSON messages in the `error` callback of `jQuery.ajax`.